# Merge a 1 x N array to a 1 x 1 array without using loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 1 x N double array and I would like to merge it to become a 1 x 1 array.

E.g.
`K = [0,1,1,1];`

I want K to become `K = [0111];`

How do I do it?

Comment: I've edited, as my double array only contain 0 and 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a cute way of doing it in one line:

```
>> K = [1 2 3 4];
>> K*10.^(length(K)-1:-1:0)'
ans =
        1234
```

EDIT: new, super short way now.

Comment: This works. But this is not what I want, its my fault as my question is flawed. I will post another question again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are merging an array of zeroes and ones into a single value, you're going to have trouble representing it properly as a *double* value. This is because any leading zeroes on the left hand side of the number won't be displayed when it's a double. However, you can represent the string of zeroes and ones as a *character* array. A neat little trick for doing this is as follows:

```
>> K = [0,1,1,1];
>> char(K+'0')

ans =

0111
```

When you add a vector of doubles (`K`) and a scalar string (`'0'`), the string gets converted to it's ASCII/Unicode value (`48` in this case). `K+'0'` becomes the vector `[48 49 49 49]`, and the [CHAR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/char.html) function changes these values to their equivalent ASCII/Unicode characters, creating a character array.

Answer (score 0):

From your example I'm guessing you just want to concatenate the elements of a vector (seeing that `k=[0111]` actually stores the number `111`). Therefore if you want to keep them as they are, we use a string instead:

```
>> K = [0,1,1,1];
>> str = sprintf('%d', K)
str =
0111
>> whos str
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
  str       1x4                 8  char
```